# Visable screen judder 60hz, ubuntu 18

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, display, intel-graphics

I have an Asus Zenbook with a generic Intel graphics adapter. When I set the refresh rate to 60 Hz in Ubuntu, i get a visible judder, even on still images. The problem disappears when set to 120 Hz. When I boot to Windows, there is no screen vibration.